Compile C++ Shared Object library to Web assembly
I have C++ data.so shared object library that was compiled for linux_x86 architecture.
I would like to write my application in C++, link to the shared object library but build both of them together with web assembly as a target, I tried with Emscripten and it produces an ouput.wasm.
when dumping the wasm i get
asm-objdump -h output.wasm
0000004: error: bad magic value


I don't think that WebAssembly offers shared libraries.

The Makefile below is a working example that first compiles a shared emscripten library WASM_LIB=tmp/lib.bc, and that is then used to quickly compile the Wasm file on iterations. Should save a lot of time to use the prebuilt lib.bc file since it's only built once.
https://github.com/anthumchris/opus-stream-decoder/blob/master/Makefile
